# Subprocess Popen will not terminate after Traceback Error:

Tags: python

In my python script I issue a "Connect command" to my Target Machine. End of each script I issue a "disconnect command". The script works fine thru subprocess (connect and disconnect) as far as there is no error raised.

The issue I am facing here as shown in below case, where Key Value error is raised, leaves my process hanging even though I have given an "except" it wont do anything. I guess since the script had initiated a Connect command
its still holding on to it. I dont know how to force kill the Popen process for below . Please Help !!!. I am using Python25

```
try:# I am creating subprocess to run my python scripts  
    retcode = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('python '' ' + "'%s'"%      (PythonTestScript) + ' ' ), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    #is done for parallel printing to Console and a file that works just fine
    while True:  
          output = retcode.stdout.readline()
          if output == ''and retcode.poll() is not None:
             break
          if output:
             print output.strip()
             outputfile.write(output)
except OSError, e:
      print >>sys.stderr, "Execution failed:", e
      returnvalue = os.popen('TASKKILL /PID '+str(retcode.pid)+' /F')
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "PythonTestScript", line 27, in 
LocalDict('Name','Age','Date')
KeyError: ('Name','Age','Date')

Comment: The error is raised in the subprocess so your `except OSError, e:` exception isn't reached, but your `if output == ''and retcode.poll() is not None:` should hit and break out of the loop... unless the child process itself doesn't terminate on the error. I think its the child that needs debugged.

Comment: Thanks for you response. This is working now. I added exception in child process and it worked.!